# jasmine: Mocking angular service yields timeout

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-service, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test an angular service. The service is using another service and I would like to mock that one.

Let's say I have a service `myService` that depends on the service `myOtherService`. When just testing the application I get

```
Unknown provider: myOtherServiceProvider <- myOtherService <- myService
```

This is because I have not included the file specifing the service in the unit test. And I also don't want because I would like to mock this service.

I have come across this [reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/mocking-dependencies-angularjs-tests/) and have tried to with something like that:

```
describe('Service: myService', function() {
    var myService;

    beforeEach(function(){module('myApp');});

    beforeEach(function($provide){
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.service('myOtherService', function() {
                this.doSomething = function(){
                    //...
                }
            });
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_myService_) {
        myService = _myService_;
    }));

    describe('Duck Typing', function() {
        it('should contain a doSomething() API function', function(){
            expect(angular.isFunction(myService.doSomething)).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

But when running the unit test I get the following error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

So I would like to learn what is wrong here and how I can mock the service dependency correctly.

Thanks!